# Starting a personal reuasable code repository

Tags: language-agnostic, resources

I've been meaning to start a library of reusable code snippets for a while and never seem to get round to it. At the moment I just tend to have some transient classes/files that I drag out of old projects.

I think my main problems are:

- Where to start. What structure should
  my repository take? Should it be a
  compiled library (where appropriate)
  or just classes/files I can drop into
  any project? Or a library project
  that can be included? What are the
  licencing implications of that?
- In my experience, a built/minified
  library will quickly become out of
  date and the source will get lost. So
  I'm leaning towards source that I can
  export from SVN and include in any
  project.
- Intellectual property. I am
  employeed, so a lot of the code I
  write is not my IP. How can I ensure
  that I don't give my own IP away
  using it on projects in work and at
  home? I'm thinking the best way would
  be to licence my library with an open
  source licence and make sure I only
  add to it in my own time using my own
  equipment and therefore making sure
  that if I use it in a work project
  the same rules apply as if I was
  using a third party library.
- I write in many different languages
  and often would require two or more
  parts of this library.
- Should I look at implementing a few
  template projects and a core project
  for each of my chosen reusable
  components and languages?

Has anyone else got this sort of library and how do you organise and update it?

Comment: This isn't language agnostic. How you design & create a library depends greatly on what language(s) you are using.

Comment: It is language agnostic. I'm not talking about a "library" as in jquery or Lucene, I'm talking about organising my own SVN repository to include code snippets for multiple languages that I can use in many different scenarios. I don't want a DLL that I just drop into projects. Sorry if that's not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule number one. If you want to use it for yourself, don't use it at work and don't work on it at work. Even under those conditions some employers will think they own it even if you worked on it during the time period (calendar time) you worked for them. Some may even be more ridiculous than that. So don't even mention that it exists.

Having said that, putting it under a BSD license on sourceforge may allow you to use it with you NEXT employer provided you clarify the ground rules upfront - tell them you're grabbing such a library and possibly that you wrote it.

IANAL - I am not a lawyer. You may want to consult with one.

I prefer to work on my stuff on my time and my machines and just never mention it. Then when companies ask me to sign one of those "we own all your stuff" I make sure it doesn't apply to stuff at home - this has required getting it amended in some cases. Even in that case, if I wanted to use the code at work I'd worry that I may lose ownership because some of those lines have been blurred.

Don't worry about reinventing the wheel. They pay you to write software. And when life really kicks in you'll have less time for hobby programming anyway ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a lightweight approach:

- Use Git or Mercurial, possibly with Dropbox if you don't want it hosted: you want version control no matter what you're doing, and distributed version control is especially perfect if you don't plan on sharing; no central repository needed
- **Save whatever you use.** Don't spend time creating code because you think you'll reuse it later; wait until you're about to write it twice before you add any work. Then throw the duplicated work in there, and you'll be ready if it happens a 3rd time.
- Make a directory per language; you can't reuse Java in Python, after all

Here's one directory structure you could try:

```
+ src
|    + python
|    |     + emailing
|    |     |    // the source goes in here
|    |     + quick-profiling
|    + java
|    + c++
+ notes
    // This may not be your thing, but it's a convenient place for them
```

Answer (score 1):

As Neil said, a lot of the implementation details of the answer depend on your language.

However, you make 2 very valid points:

- it's better to have the library in source code form even for compiled languages, for obvious reasons
- If you wish to retain the IP and use it outside of work, then do it 100% outside of work, license with some very permissive license. Something like the [zlib license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/zlib-license.html) might be appropriate.

One more point though - **You are better off if you make sure your employer is OK with using that code!!!**. You can publish it anonymously/under a pseudonym if that permission is hard/infeasible to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your idea, and with the concept of code snippets in general, is that it falls down badly if your snippet has a bug in it. For the snippet approach, you will have to fix the bug in the source code of all of the applications that used the snippet. If on the other hand you build binary libraries, you simply need to fix the bug once in the library code, test it there, relink, run your app's regression tests, and you are done. This is why professional programmers abhor code snippets.

Comment: Very fair comment, perhaps the patterns are better left in my head.